# Javascript array longer than 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have made an array and am trying to print out all the words that are longer than 4 letters.

Here is my code:

```
function oppC(){
        var ord = ["Apple", "Two", "Yesterday", "mother", "lol", "car", "computer"];
        for(var i = 4; i < ord.length;i++ ) {
            pEl.innerHTML = ord;
        }
        }
```

Comment: `if (ord[i].length > 4) ...` anyone…? Too obvious?

Comment: `pEl.innerHTML += ord[i];`, `+=` otherwise text will overwritten by last statement and `[i]` to access array element

Answer (score 1):

You should use `filter` function.

Here is solution.

```js
function oppC(){
        var ord = ["Apple", "Two", "Yesterday", "mother", "lol", "car", "computer"];
        console.log(ord.filter(function(item){
              return item.length>4;
        }));
 }
oppC();
```

If you are using IE8, please try this:

```
console.log($.grep(ord,function(item){
         return item.length>4;
}));
```

Comment: You've included jQuery. I guess it's for backward compatibility of `filter` (which does not work natively in IE8), but you're not using it. If you want this to work on IE8, you'll want to do `$(ord).filter(function(){ return this.length>4; });`, otherwise, there is no point in including jQuery here.

Comment: Thanks for your point. I updated answer for IE8, I know that `jquery grep` is a better solution than `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

With your current for loop, you're only looking at the 5th element onward. If you want it to get **all** strings longer than 4 characters you can do this:

```
function oopC(){
    var ord = ["Apple", "Two", "Yesterday", "mother", "lol", "car", "computer"];
    for(var i = 0; i < ord.length; i++){ // cycle through **all** elements, because arrays start with 0
        if(ord[i].length > 4){ // if the element length is greater than 4
            pEl.innerHTML += ord[i]; // add element to the textview
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code, no need of any javascript library

```
function oppC(){
    var ord = new Array("Apple", "Two", "Yesterday", "mother", "lol", "car", "computer");
    for(var i = 0; i < ord.length; i++) {
        if(ord[i].length > 4){
            document.write(ord[i]+"<br>");
        }
    }
}

oppC();
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to add an if condition inside the loop to check if length is greater than 4.

```
function oppC() {
    var ord = ["Apple", "Two", "Yesterday", "mother", "lol", "car", "computer"];
    for (var i = 0; i < ord.length; i++) {
        if (ord[i].length > 4) {
            pEl.innerHTML += ord[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution. The CSS is just to show, how the items are added.

```js
function oppC(){
        var pEl = document.getElementById("output");
        var ord = ["Apple", "Two", "Yesterday", "mother", "lol", "car", "computer"];
        for(var i = 0; i < ord.length;i++ ) {
            if (ord[i].length > 4) {
              pEl.innerHTML += '<div class="long-item">' + ord[i] + '</div>';
            }
        }
    }

oppC();
```

```css
.output-list {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.long-item {
  color: #333;
  font-family: monospace;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output" class="output-list">
</div>
```